# Interactive networkx Graph Webpage in Python

Tags: python, django, pygame, networkx, pyglet

I'm building an app in Python which I would like to make available on the web.  On the server side I will have a networkx graph of nodes and links, each of which will have their own pictoral representation.  I'm looking for a way to represent this graph on my webpage, and looking for something that will be interactive and aesthetically pleasing.  The interactivity required is that I need the user to be able to interact with the graph in an intuitive way, adding nodes and links, getting info about existing nodes, etc.  It would conceptually be somewhat similar to mohiomap in web interface.

I've looked into django and flask, but I don't understand if this could be accomplished using these libraries.  It seems like fairly graphic oriented content, more like a game than anything.  I was looking at pygame and thought that using pyjsdl this might be more appropriate.  My question is, is the above something that could be achieved with python.  What would be the preferred language/library?  I've looked at django and flask, but am wondering if pyglet or pygame may be actually more appropriate for this task.  I mainly want to avoid going to deep into anything before I understand conceptually what constructs best fit the described purpose!

I realise this question is currently vague, please advise how I can make it more specific and I will update.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site isn't appropriate for asking for tutorials, libraries or any other off site information.

Comment: From the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: Ok, I can delete my question if it's perceived that way.  To be clear, I'm not asking for specific libraries, I'm more trying to understand what genre of libraries would be used for the given task.  Does that make sense?  Again, I don't mind deleting this, it's just that I've been searching for weeks to figure out what tools are most well suited to this task and I haven' been able to figure it out.

Comment: I might be wrong as well so there's no need deleting it until a moderator says so. I was just providing the information I seemed fit to get you a chance to edit your question, but I might have misinterpret your question. I cannot understand it quite but that might be because the time of the day. I can't help you, unfortunately.

Comment: web browser can execute only JavaScript so you will have to learn JavaScript and use JavaScripts libraries in browser plus Django/Flask on server. PyGame/Pyglet will be useless.

Comment: BTW: see [JSNetworkX](http://jsnetworkx.org/)

Comment: I see, so I think that answers my question... I should not be trying to put my python on the web, I should be using javascript with Django/Flask on server side.  Mind putting it as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browser can execute only JavaScript so you will have to learn JavaScript and use JavaScript libraries in browser plus Django/Flask on server.

PyGame/Pyglet will be useless.

There are tools to [conver Python to JavaScript](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3033047/javascript/4-tools-to-convert-python-to-javascript-and-back-again.html) but it may not be so usefull like pure JavaScript or existing libraries in JavaScript.

BTW: see [JSNetworkX](http://jsnetworkx.org/)